# Rspec Test Always Passes Regardless Of Input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, automated-tests, tdd

I'm trying to test the below method in my connect-four game. When a player tries to place a piece in a full column, `:puts` and error message to the screen.

The problem I'm running into is that the test passes regardless of whether I input a board with a full column or an empty column. I'm also seeing this error message: `` WARNING: An expectation of `:puts` was set on `nil`. `` Which I interpret to mean that the `board` or `@player` value is not being properly passed into the final `expect()` assignment.

Where am I going wrong with this test? Thank you!

**Method being tested:**

```
def valid_vertical_move
  until @game_board.board[5][@player - 1] == '.'
    puts 'Please place piece in valid spot'
    player_selection
  end
end
```

**This is one of the many tests I've tried:**

```
describe Game do

  describe '#valid_vertical_move' do
    subject(:valid_move) { described_class.new(new_board) }
    let(:new_board) {double('new_board', :board => [['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', '.', '.', '.'], 
      ['y', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['y', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
      ['y', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['x', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
      ['x', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']])}

    context 'when the column is full' do

      before do
        allow(valid_move).to receive(:player_selection)
      end

      it 'an error message is :puts' do
         error_message = 'Please place piece in valid spot'
         test = valid_move.valid_vertical_move
         expect(test).to receive(:puts).with(error_message)

      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Game Class:**

```
class Game

  attr_reader :player

  def initialize(game_board = Board.new)
    @game_board = game_board
    @player_turn = 1
    @player = 0
  end

  def player_selection
    loop do
      puts "Choose a column, Player #{@player_turn}:"
      @user_input = gets.chomp

      if @user_input.match?(/\b[1-7]\b/)
        return @player = @user_input.to_i
      else
        puts 'Error: Add number between 1-7'
      end
    end
  end

  def valid_vertical_move
    until @game_board.board[5][@player - 1] == '.'
      puts 'Please place piece in valid spot'
      player_selection
    end
  end
end
```

**Board class:**

```
class Board
  attr_reader :board

  def initialize(board = Array.new(6) { Array.new(['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']) })
    @board = board
  end

  def display_board(board = @board)
    puts "| #{board[5][0]} | #{board[5][1]} | #{board[5][2]} | #{board[5][3]} | #{board[5][4]} | #{board[5][5]} | #{board[5][6]} |"
    puts "| #{board[4][0]} | #{board[4][1]} | #{board[4][2]} | #{board[4][3]} | #{board[4][4]} | #{board[4][5]} | #{board[4][6]} |"
    puts "| #{board[3][0]} | #{board[3][1]} | #{board[3][2]} | #{board[3][3]} | #{board[3][4]} | #{board[3][5]} | #{board[3][6]} |"
    puts "| #{board[2][0]} | #{board[2][1]} | #{board[2][2]} | #{board[2][3]} | #{board[2][4]} | #{board[2][5]} | #{board[2][6]} |"
    puts "| #{board[1][0]} | #{board[1][1]} | #{board[1][2]} | #{board[1][3]} | #{board[1][4]} | #{board[1][5]} | #{board[1][6]} |"
    puts "| #{board[0][0]} | #{board[0][1]} | #{board[0][2]} | #{board[0][3]} | #{board[0][4]} | #{board[0][5]} | #{board[0][6]} |"
    puts "  1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7  "
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically ur expecting a nil `test = valid_move.valid_vertical_move` to receive a method call which is not what you seem to want to do here. You would want to raise or log some error here and then test for Rails.logger to receive some call or something.